# Mod_jk Tomcat VirtualHost

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost, mod-jk

I have two applications in Tomcat app1 and app2.

I have mod_jk configured for Apache front end and I am able to get the Tomcat index.jsp

Now I created two virtualhosts for app1 and app2 so that app1.domain.com will point to app1 in tomcat and app2.domain.com will point to app2 in Tomcat but it's not working.

I have the Vhost as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.app1.domain.com
ServerAlias app1.domain.com
DocumentRoot "/opt/tomcat/webapps/app1"
<Directory "/opt/tomcat/webapps/app1">
  DirectoryIndex index.jsp
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
###### The following section added for Jk
JkMount /*.do ajp13
JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
JkMount / ajp13
JkMount /* ajp13
JkUnMount /*.php ajp13
JkUnMount /*.gif ajp13
JkUnMount /*.html ajp13
JkUnMount /*.css ajp13
JkUnMount /*.png ajp13
JkUnMount /*.jpg ajp13
######
#</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But this did not work both the sub domains loads Tomcat's index.jsp.

Can some one help me?

Thanks

Comment: Abandon mod_jk and use mod_proxy_ajp instead.

Answer (score -1):

I got it I done it through a RewriteRule.

Thanks,
Anoop

Comment: It would have been nice if you posted your solution here.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry I was on vacation. Did you get it solved? Do you need any help?

Comment: @user37143 I think the point is to catalog the solution here so other people can benefit from it.